# What happens when an element in the domain set has theoretically more than one image in the co-domain set?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I have a very stupid question that i unnecessarily got stuck on. I'm studying functions and came upon the fact that the elements in the domain set cannot have multiple images in the co-domain.
I asked myself the following:
What if there is a domain x = {4, 9, 16} and a co-domain y = {-4, -3, -2, 2, 3, 4} with f(x) = √x.
With that all the elements in the domain would have to have two images since the result of a root of a number can be either positive and negative.
Now I get it that you aren't allowed to have two images of a domain element in a function, but what happens in this case?
Is the specified co-domain not allowed for the specified domain?
Is the function invalid because it creates more images than it should?
Is there a term or an area in mathematics that works with cases like this one, a special type of "functions" or "relations" where multiple images are allowed? Or does this simply not exist? (I would've satisfied myself with the answer "it just doesn't exist and thats it", but somehow i've come to a conclusion that in mathematics, simply everything does exist.)
Thanks in advance to anyone who will take time to shed some light on my dilemma.

Comment: What definition of *'function'* are you working with?

Comment: It exists - it is a relation, and it is *not* a function. You can, however, make it a function if you decide to restrict to a single image for every element of the domain. Which is what we do when we define $\sqrt{x}$ as the *non-negative* number whose square is $x$,

Comment: You can do a search for *multi-valued functions*. The name is a misnomer, since, strictly speaking, if it's multi-valued, it's not a function, but people use the term, anyway.

Comment: Way too many questions in one post.  I count six questions, at least.  Please try to focus on *the main point or two* that you are struggling with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function from $A$ to $B$ is a relation from $A$ to $B$.

In means that any function from $A$ to $B$ is a set of ordered pairs $(x,y)$ with $x\in A$ and $y\in B$.

Consider this function $f$ from $A= \{a,b,c\}$ to $B= \{1,2,3\}$.

$f=\{(a,1) , (b,1), (c,3)\}$.

This function is a relation ( from $A$ to $B$).

Now, let's change $f$ ( so to say) into $F$ by introducting the ordered pair $(a, 3)$ in $f$. We get :

$F = \{(a,1) , (b,1), (c,3), (a,3)\}$.

In becoming $F$, the set  $f$ hasn't lost its status of relation ( from $A$ to $B$) , but it does no longer enjoy its previous status of function.

The relation defined by " number $y$ is the square root of number $x$" is a function from $[0, +\infty]$ to $\mathbb R$.

But the relation " number $y$ is a number such that $y\times y=x$ " is not a function , because , for example, both the pair $(16,4)$ and the pair $(16, -4)$ belong to this relation.

Note : the square root function is defined by " $y=\sqrt {x} $ if and only if $y\times y=x$ ***and*** $y\geq 0$ "

There is a branch of logic that sudies relations as such. It is sometimes called the " calculus of relations" . See Alonzo Church's article on Logic in Runes' *Dictionary Of Philosophy*  (https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.214622/page/n7/mode/2up).

Note : when I said that a functon "becomes" a relation, I'm not talking rigorously; in fact, a set cannot undergo any form of  change, because the identity of a set totally depends on its members ( due to extensionnality principle).